# graphics setColor - What are the parameters?

Tags: java

What is the last parameter in setColor method?

```
g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: If in doubt look at the javadocs  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html):

> Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)
>   Creates an sRGB color with the specified red, green, blue, and alpha values in the range (0 - 255).

Description of the "Alpha Value":

> Every color has an implicit alpha value of 1.0 or an explicit one provided in the constructor. The alpha value defines the transparency of a color and can be represented by a float value in the range 0.0 - 1.0 or 0 - 255. An alpha value of 1.0 or 255 means that the color is completely opaque and an alpha value of 0 or 0.0 means that the color is completely transparent. When constructing a Color with an explicit alpha or getting the color/alpha components of a Color, the color components are never premultiplied by the alpha component.

As a result, the `new Color(r, g, b)` is equivalent to `new Color(r, g, b, 1);`